# Cartesian product of a variable number of sets each of variable size

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, set, cartesian-product

Let G be some object.

Let n = f(G) be the number of sets.

Let S<sub>i</sub> = {1,2, ..., h(i) - 1, h(i)} with 1 ≤ i ≤ n.

I want to write a method (Java) that returns a twodimensional array representing the cartesian product S = S<sub>1</sub> X S<sub>2</sub> X ... X S<sub>n-1</sub> X S<sub>n</sub>. The intention of the method is shown in java-like pseudocode below. It implies an iterative solution, but a recursive solution is also ok.

```
int[][] varCart(G, j) {
      int[][] result = new int[sizeOfCartProduct][f(G)]
      ....
      return result;
}
```

Additionally, S<sub>j</sub> is changed to { 1 } (or any other singleton).

---

As an example:

Let G be the object so that:

f(G) = 3

S<sub>1</sub> = {1,2} [h(1) = 2]

S<sub>2</sub> = {1,2,3} [h(2) = 3]

S<sub>3</sub> = {1,2,3,4} [h(3) = 4]

And let j = 2.

Then the result of varCart(G,2) must be

> int[2*1*4 = 8][3] = {{1,1,1},{1,1,2},{1,1,3},{1,1,4},{2,1,1},{2,1,2},{2,1,3},{2,1,4}}

Comment: Please elaborate downvotes.

Comment: generally people would like to see some attempts at writing the code, rather than just telling us the problem you've been given and asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: I see. Let me stress though that this is a problem I encountered myself and is by no means some kind of assignment given to me.

Comment: @Auberon, have you tried coding this?

Comment: @JonathanM I haven't tried actual code since I couldn't figure it out on paper. Maybe this question was more fitting for CS stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array with the maximum value per digit; in your example, that would be `[2,3,4]`.
Set the maximum of digit `j` to 1, so you get `[2,1,4]`.
Create a first combination `[1,1,1]` and add it to the result. Then repeatedly increment the combination and add it to the result.
To increment the combination, increment the last digit; if that digit equals the maximum, set it to `1` and increment the previous digit, and so on. If the first digit needs to be incremented and it's already set to the maximum value, you've found all combinations.

```
[1,1,1] -> [1,1,2] -> [1,1,3] -> [1,1,4] ->
4 is maximum for last digit, so set it to 1 and increment previous digit ->
1 is maximum for second digit, so set it to 1 and increment previous digit ->
[2,1,1] -> [2,1,2] -> [2,1,3] -> [2,1,4] ->
4 is maximum for last digit, so set it to 1 and increment previous digit ->
1 is maximum for second digit, so set it to 1 and increment previous digit ->
2 is maximum for first digit, so all combinations have been found.
```